# TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate Transaction; Transaction not started

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions, jakarta-ee

I have a test causing an error because of Hibernate. I have no idea how to resolve this problem. This is the stacktrace:

```
 org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:677)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:823)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:800)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener$TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:501)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:277)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:170)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:344)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:307)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$RunBeforesThenTestThenAfters.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:338)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:197)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:160)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:183)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:674)
    ... 24 more
```

This is what the test causing the error looks like:

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void shouldNotBeAbleToAddCandidateWhenEmailAlreadyExistsInDatabase() {
    Candidate c = new Candidate();
    c.setEmail(EMAIL);
    c.setCompany(CompanyTest.createDefaultCompany());
    userDAO.create(c);
    Candidate candidateFromDb = (Candidate) userDAO.find(c.getId());
    assertEquals(c, candidateFromDb);

    Candidate failingCandidate = new Candidate();
    failingCandidate.setEmail(EMAIL);
    failingCandidate.setCompany(CompanyTest.createDefaultCompany());


    boolean foundDuplicate = false;
    try {
        userDAO.create(failingCandidate);
    } catch (DuplicateEmailException duplicateEmailException) {
        foundDuplicate = true;
    }
    assertTrue(foundDuplicate);
}
```

This is what the Transaction Manager in applicatipnContext-dao.xml looks like:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

This is the applicationContext.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd"
    default-autowire="byName">

    <bean id="dataConfigPropertyConfigurer"
                class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:${app.env}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="wicketConfiguration" class="com.firmfactory.work.WicketConfiguration">
        <property name="configurationMode" value="development" />
        <property name="showStacktrace" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.firmfactory.work.daos" />
    <import resource="applicationContext-controllers.xml" />
    <import resource="applicationContext-services.xml" />

    <bean name="dataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource">
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/workt?characterEncoding=UTF-8</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>work</value>
        </property>
        <property name="////">

        <!-- <value>work</value> -->
             <value>////</value>

        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
REMOVED SOME MODELS

        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.spring.SpringLiquibase">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:DbChangeSet.xml" />
    </bean>-->

    <bean id="resumeInformationPriceString" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="25"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="candidateInformationPriceString" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="75"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="deafaultCompanyId" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <constructor-arg value="1"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="uploadPath" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="/home/hudson/uploads/"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="logoPath" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="../logos/"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

**Edited** applicationContext.xml as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    "
    default-autowire="byName">

    <bean id="dataConfigPropertyConfigurer"
                class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyOverrideConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:${app.env}.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="wicketConfiguration" class="com.firmfactory.work.WicketConfiguration">
        <property name="configurationMode" value="development" />
        <property name="showStacktrace" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.firmfactory.work.daos" />
    <import resource="applicationContext-controllers.xml" />
    <import resource="applicationContext-services.xml" />

    <bean name="dataSource" class="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource">
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/work?characterEncoding=UTF-8</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>work</value>
        </property>
        <property name="///">

        <!-- <value>work</value> -->
             <value>///</value>

        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <removed propertys of models>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.transaction">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean id="transactionManager" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"
        p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <!-- <bean id="liquibase" class="liquibase.spring.SpringLiquibase">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="changeLog" value="classpath:DbChangeSet.xml" />
    </bean>-->

    <bean id="resumeInformationPriceString" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="25"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="candidateInformationPriceString" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="75"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="deafaultCompanyId" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <constructor-arg value="1"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="uploadPath" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="/home/hudson/uploads/"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="logoPath" class="java.lang.String">
        <constructor-arg value="../logos/"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>



</beans>
```

**New** (seemingly identical?) stacktrace:

```
 org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not roll back Hibernate transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:677)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:823)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:800)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener$TransactionContext.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:501)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.endTransaction(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:277)
    at org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener.afterTestMethod(TransactionalTestExecutionListener.java:170)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.afterTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:344)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runAfters(SpringMethodRoadie.java:307)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie$RunBeforesThenTestThenAfters.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:338)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runWithRepetitions(SpringMethodRoadie.java:217)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.runTest(SpringMethodRoadie.java:197)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringMethodRoadie.run(SpringMethodRoadie.java:143)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.invokeTestMethod(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:160)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.runMethods(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:51)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner$1.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:37)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit4ClassRunner.run(JUnit4ClassRunner.java:42)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: Transaction not successfully started
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:183)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doRollback(HibernateTransactionManager.java:674)
    ... 24 more
```

Comment: your transaction configuration? code?

Comment: Added the code. Where can I find my transaction configuration?

Comment: Probably in the applicationContext.xml file where the hibernate session factory is defined. Look for something like `<tx:annotation-based />`

Comment: Was it the Transaction Manager that you ment? I added the one from the applicationContext-dao file (the DAO is causing the error). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

add this conf. in your application-context.xml

```
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>



    <!-- Transaction manager for a single Hibernate SessionFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"  p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory">
    </bean>
```

hibernate.properties should contain

```
org.hibernate.transaction true
```

Test class should be configured like

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"/yourapplication-context.xml"})
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class MyTest {
```

Note: not all fields may be required , I have just shown a working conf.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added this in the applicationContext but got the error: The prefix "p" for attribute "p:sessionFactory-ref" associated with an element type "bean" is not bound.

Comment: I get "The annotation <annotation> is disallowed for this location" for all of the annotations.

Comment: @Emil where did you get this ? `The annotation <annotation> is disallowed for this location` ?

Comment: In the testclass. I annotated the test and made the proper imports, but still get the message like : "The annotation @RunWith is disallowed for this location"

Comment: @Emil I hope you have imported the same classes, please verify it, Check updated answer

Comment: Yes, the imports look identical. I am currently running JUnit 3 for all my tests, could that be the problem?

Comment: @Emil can be be I am using 4.4 try out with that

Comment: My bad. I was annotating the test, not the testclass. 
The only problem that remains now is this: The prefix "p" for attribute "p:sessionFactory-ref" associated with an element type "bean" is not bound. (in applicationContext.xml)

Comment: @Emil add `xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"` in your schemalocation section of xml file

Comment: Thanks. I added the changes in applicationContext and annotated correctly in the testclass, but the error is still the same. The one part I'm unsure of is the Hibernate property. I tried with: <prop key="org.hibernate.transaction">true</prop> and <prop key="hibernate.transaction">true</prop> but noone of them made any difference. Any clue on what I might be missing?

Comment: @Emil it is not nesessary to add, by same error message you mean the error for xmlns `p:` ??

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I mean the TransactionSystemException when I run the test.

Comment: @Emil can you post stacktrace for it

Comment: I added the new stacktrace. Unfortunatly as far as I can tell it's identical to before I made any changes.

Comment: No I am not. I've now decided to go with a completely different approach as I don't really see myself finding a solution to this problem any time soon.